# why does pyautogui.mouseDown() performs the same as pyautogui.Click()?

Tags: python, pyautogui, mousedown, mouseup

I am trying to write a simple python bot to auto click tiles in [piano tile 2](https://poki.co.il/g/piano-tiles-2)

The problem is, I am trying to tell the bot to perform a long mouse click and release if the tile ends. But instead it clicks and automatically releases even though I used `pyautogui.mouseDown()` and never told it to do `mouseUp()`. this is my code:

***code***

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time
from mss import mss
import keyboard

start_x = 983
start_y = 474

cords_x = [0, 90, 177, 251]

bbox = (start_x,start_y,start_x+252,start_y + 4)

def start():
    with mss() as sct:
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                break
            img = sct.grab(bbox)
            for cord in cords_x:
                if img.pixel(cord,0)[0] < 100:
                    pg.moveTo(start_x+cord,start_y)
                    pg.mouseDown(button='left')
                    if img.pixel(cord,2)[0] > 154:
                        pg.mouseUp(button='left')
                        break

time.sleep(3)
start()
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue and the only way it works for now is by repeatedly calling `mouseDown()`. I'm gonna keep searching